# How to use deconv() instead of roots() on MATLAB to find roots to a polynomial

Tags: matlab, transfer-function, deconvolution, poles-zeros

I recently read that for polynomials of degree 5 or more, when executed with the roots() command on MATLAB produces an error. The documentation said as follows:
[image]

[image]

As a substitute, using the deconv() in-built function was recommended. How do we find accurate roots to a polynomial using deconv()? I can't seem to figure it out

Comment: I think this question is OK. In polynomial world convolution is like multiplication of the polynomials and deconvolution is division. Both are very related to analysis of Filters.